# How does Jester interact with the Knights?

Tags: dominion, dominion-cornucopia, dominion-dark-ages

Each of the Knights has a different name. If someone reveals a Knight when I play a Jester, can I gain a Knight, or do I gain nothing since there isn't a second Dame Anne (or whomever) available in the supply?

[image: Jester]

Comment: The same situation arises if there are none of those cards left in the supply or when the card is gained via some other specific card (tournament prizes & black market)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Golden Rule of Dominion is "do as much as you can".

If no copies of a card exist (e.g. because they've all been trashed) then no card is given out by a Jester.

Since Knights are unique cards, **no-one gains anything** when a Jester reveals one.

Comment: This is what we thought, and how we played it, but we couldn't find a definitive answer in the rules for either card.

Comment: As @swbarnes2's comment indicates, this answer is not quite complete; Dame Josephine is a Victory card, so in that particular case, her owner gains a Curse.

Answer (score 8):

If Dame Jospheine is revealed, she is a Victory card,so that triggers the first text on Jester, and the player owning her gets a Curse.